# Prove that $ f(0) \neq 0 $.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be a non-constant function such that $ f(a + b) = f(a) \times f(b) $ for all real numbers $ a $ and $ b $.

a) Prove that $ f(0) \neq 0 $. (**Hint:** Otherwise, $ f(x) = 0 $ for all $ x \in \mathbb{R} $.)

b) Use Part (a) to prove that $ f(0) = 1 $.

**EDIT:** I had spent about 10 hours trying to figure this problem out with no headway.  I had talked to other people in my class who shared a similar story.  Between the three of us, we (after the first answer was posted) were able determine is was exponential, but that was about it.

Comment: Is this HW? If so, it should be tagged as such. Can you tell us your thoughts on the problem and things you've considered so we may provide guidance? Regards

Comment: @Amzoti Sorry, this is my first time using Mathematics on StackExchange.  As far as thoughts go, I was pretty much completely lost until the first answer.

Comment: No problem, we collectively monitor the site to try and have a standard approach and there is a lot of great info worth reviewing (and I myself am still learning) in the [*MSE FAQ*](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq). Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting $b=0,f(a)=f(a)\cdot f(0)\implies f(a)\{f(0)-1\}=0$

If $f(0)=0,-f(a)=0\implies f(a)=0$ a constant function

So, $f(0)\ne0,$ putting $a=0, f(0)=f^2(0)\implies f(0)=1$

---

Alternatively, 
Also, $f$ is a non-constant function, we shall definitely find some $a$ such that $f(a)\ne0$

so $f(0)=1\ne0$

Comment: Thank you, that makes so much sense.  I have literally spent all day trying to figure that one out.

Comment: @ChrisCrutchfield, my pleasure. Observe that the 1st method is the puritan answer of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Notice one more thing:

$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ $\implies$ This is a exponential function.

(There is a function which is not exponential function,  But in view of the differentiability at x=0, it must reduce to a power function.)

Therefore, $f(x)=a^x \implies f(0)=1 \neq0$.

Comment: "in view of the differentiability at x=0": Where did this assumption come from?  Terminology note:  $x\mapsto a^x$ is more commonly called an exponential function, while $x\mapsto x^a$ is a power function.

Comment: Woo! I meant, Exponential.